# Get String From Text PHP

Tags: php

i need help master PHP
I have many content structure like this :

```
Spesifikasi Tas Karakter Anak Laki-Laki
Merk : Garsel Fashion
Tahun Edisi : 2017
Kode : KKM 5885
Warna : Merah Kombinasi
Ukuran : 29x39x13 (Panduan Ukuran) 
Bahan : D-300
Garansi : 30 Hari
```

I want to get data string from warna like "Merah Kombinasi"
How can i extract that content. 
Thanks full

Comment: Do you read the content from a file?

Comment: yes, i have handle it, but i need function to extract that string to get data value from warna

Comment: for example i want to get "Merah Kombinasi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **regex**. It will find all text after **Warna :** on the **same line**

```
$str="Spesifikasi Tas Karakter Anak Laki-Laki
Merk : Garsel Fashion
Tahun Edisi : 2017
Kode : KKM 5885
Warna : Merah Kombinasi
Ukuran : 29x39x13 (Panduan Ukuran) 
Bahan : D-300
Garansi : 30 Hari";
preg_match_all("/(?<=Warna :).*?(?=\n)/",
    $str,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($out);
```

output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Merah Kombinasi ) )
```

Read this : http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: this work for me but i have NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number 16
Array

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended for large files, but you could do something simple, as this:

```
$lines = file('your-text-file.txt');
$result = [];
foreach($lines as $line){
    list($key, $value) = explode(' : ', $line);

    // Save the result in the array or echo out here
    $result[$key] = $value;
}

echo $result['Warna'];
```

I would also make a strtolower on the key and maybe replace spaces with nothing and so on. Just to prevent stupid errors.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i just want to get value from Warna

Comment: That is also what you are getting. You could use preg_match_all to run through all the text and get only that, but this is easier if you later on are going to use any other fields.

Comment: not working, 
function convert_warna($value){
 $lines = $value;
 $result = [];
 foreach($lines as $line){
     list($key, $newvalue) = explode(' : ', $line);
     // Save the result in the array or echo out here
     $result[$key] = $newvalue;
 }
 return $result['Warna'];
}

Comment: You can use regex , try my answer